how to find a not null constraint
I am working in Azure SQL Managed Instance.  I have a table with some explicitly-named NOT NULL constraints, such as the following:
CREATE TABLE my_db.my_schema.my_table (
    my_column int CONSTRAINT nn_my_table_my_column NOT NULL
)
;

I'm trying to find where this constraint lives in the DB.  To my knowledge, NOT NULL constraints are CHECK constraints.  So, I have tried the following:
SELECT
    *
FROM
    my_db.sys.objects
WHERE
    type_desc = 'CHECK_CONSTRAINT'
;

However, no rows return.  So, either Azure SQL Managed Instance doesn't declare NOT NULL constraints as CHECK constraints, or they're saved elsewhere.  How can I find this particular constraint?

A check constraint is something else, for example: create table t (a int check a > 1) for not null, you can just check sys.columns is_nullable column. Upvoted though, because it's interesting that sql server doesn't create a named constraint for this case

my_column int CONSTRAINT nn_my_table_my_column NOT NULL doesn't actually create a CONSTRAINT. This is because there is no actual CHECK defined. You could just write the line as my_column int NOT NULL. We can confirm this by checking the sys.check_constraints and also attempting to create another CONSTRAINT with the same name:
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable (MyColumn int NOT NULL,
                          YourColumn int CONSTRAINT chk_Mytable_YourColumn NOT NULL);
GO

SELECT *
FROM sys.check_constraints
WHERE parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.MyTable');
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ADD CONSTRAINT chk_Mytable_YourColumn CHECK (YourColumn > 0);
GO

SELECT *
FROM sys.check_constraints
WHERE parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.MyTable');
GO

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.MyTable;

This returns no results for the first SELECT, only in the second, when the CREATE was successfully run. If a CONSTRAINT of the name already exists, it would have failed.
What you want to do is check if the column is NULLable or not, which is defined in sys.columns:
SELECT *
FROM sys.columns c
WHERE c.is_nullable = 0
  AND object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.MyTable');

If you really wanted to create a CHECK CONSTRAINT that did not permit NULL values, then you would define it as the following:
my_column int CONSTRAINT nn_my_table_my_column CHECK (my_column IS NOT NULL)

Though, I really suggest that's a "bad" idea; there's no need for a CHECK CONSTRAINT here.
